# C struct with dynamic array member place of allocation in memory problem

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am wondering where is foo and arr* being allocated in this sample program. Is foo allocated on stack with constant size or does it change when I use malloc on *arr? If I were to change foo.arr[i] for i from 0 to 4, would it change size of anything? Is foo.arr being allocated on heap? Does change of size of foo.arr change size of foo?

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int* arr;
} S;

int main(void) {
    S foo;
    int new_size = 5;
    foo.size = new_size;
    foo.arr = malloc(new_size * sizeof(int));

    free(foo.arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int arr*` is invalid syntax, change it to `int * arr`. A useful convention is to read typing from right to left: "identifier `arr` is a pointer `*` to an `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do `S foo;` you allocate an element of type S in the stack composed of two int, generally 32 bits for an int, so you have allocated 64 bits.
Then you do `foo.arr = malloc(new_size * sizeof(int));`, you have allocated in the heap a certain amount of contiguous bits, and now `foo.arr` will point to (`->`) the first 32 bits.

**Additional answers :**

> If I change foo.arr[i] for i from 0 to 4, would it change size of
>   anything?

No, since you will only change values in memory not size.

> Does change of size of foo.arr change size of foo?

No, from the moment `arr` is allocate on heap the size of foo will remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion stems from conflating the pointer with the allocated space. A pointer is, naively, just a variable that holds a value that describes the address in memory of another value. The space required for the pointer is determined by the maximum addressable space of architecture, not by the allocated block of memory. Think referentially.

In this case, `foo` is allocated in the stack and the size of the structure instance remains unchanged. `malloc` is taking care of the mechanics of memory allocation for you and returning a fresh memory address to the allocated space. Subsequently, you are taking that memory address and saving it in the `arr` member.

Furthermore, anything that is allocated in the stack has to be fixed size in nature. The size of the stack frame needs to be known upon calling the function. Consider the fact that every argument to a procedure has to be of known size or a pointer to some structure allocated in the heap.

Now, all that considered, there exist mechanisms to declare variable sized structures, but you would need to take care of allocating the structure in the heap and handling memory explicitly. The C99 standard introduced *flexible array member*, which allows placing a size undetermined array within a structure declaration, granted that it is accompanied by another member and it is placed as the last member of the structure.

Comment: If I were to change foo.arr[i] for i from 0 to 4, would it change size of anything?
Is foo.arr being allocated on heap? 
Does change of size of foo.arr change size of foo?

Comment: @Macher : Either post a new question or include these questions in the original question.  This is a Q&A not a conversation.   You could answer your own questions by inspection of the code and variables in a debugger.

Comment: @Clifford I disagree with you, this is a new user, he try to learn and ask additional questions to be sure he correctly understand the answer. I think this is better to post a comment than pollute with another question that is directly linked to this one.
But I agree these additional questions can be added afterwards in the original question.

Comment: @BSO : It was a general point about not asking follow-up question in comments.  Questions about the answer are fair enough, but these are new questions.  Advice for the future really.

Comment: @Clifford, I agree with you. However, my answer was rather dry and brief for a noticeably newcomer. I should have provided a *why* to the *what*.